# Limit of 16 cardreaders in pcsc on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, server, pcsc

I have 24 cardreaders in pcsc on Ubuntu server 20.04.
I have read that pcsc has a limit of 16 readers & you need to change the pcslite.h file to add more readers.
Changed the following line in /usr/include/PCSC/pcsclite.h from:
#define PCSCLITE_MAX_READERS_CONTEXTS 16

to:
#define PCSCLITE_MAX_READERS_CONTEXTS 24

Do i need to change some other files before it's working?
I still only see 16 readers connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing a C header or source files has no effect on the running program.

After editing the source file I think you should recompile the project to facilitate the changes in the executables.

Comment: How can i recompile the project?

Comment: It's usually done by running `make` in the project folder. I'm not familiar with the exact program you are using. How did you install it? There is a  chance that I came precompiled .

Comment: PCSClite page might help, is that the same program you use or an alternative? see: [this](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/PCSC), and [this](https://pcsclite.apdu.fr/).

Comment: Yes is the same program, I have compiled it but still not working

Comment: Please share a little more information, on what 'not working' looks like. It would be helpful if you showed an example. Please check out this page: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Did you replace/reinstall the software after building the new version? Also, the pcsclite.h is a generated file. Try to edit `src/PCSC/pcsclite.h.in` before running make. The fine in the `/usr` folder is for the installed program and put there automatically. You should never edit that file directly.

Comment: It’s working. I have already compiled the ccid driver

Comment: Great! Can you write down what was the solution, might be useful to others too. Also please mark the question answered it did solve your issue.

Comment: I have also changed CCID_DRIVER_MAX_READERS in src/ccid_ifdhandler.h